# How can I modify the following code to pull data from a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5, action-filter

I am using the following asp.net mvc filter to filter ips. Currently, you can specify the ip(s) in code directly or in a configuration file.  How can I modify it to pull the denied or allowed ips from a database and use that in the filter?  Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Miscellaneous.Attributes.Controller
{

/// <summary>
/// Filter by IP address
/// </summary>
public class FilterIPAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    #region Allowed
    /// <summary>
    /// Comma seperated string of allowable IPs. Example "10.2.5.41,192.168.0.22"
    /// </summary>
    /// <value></value>
    public string AllowedSingleIPs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Comma seperated string of allowable IPs with masks. Example "10.2.0.0;255.255.0.0,10.3.0.0;255.255.0.0"
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The masked I ps.</value>
    public string AllowedMaskedIPs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the configuration key for allowed single IPs
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The configuration key single I ps.</value>
    public string ConfigurationKeyAllowedSingleIPs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the configuration key allowed mmasked IPs
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The configuration key masked I ps.</value>
    public string ConfigurationKeyAllowedMaskedIPs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of allowed IPs
    /// </summary>
    IPList allowedIPListToCheck = new IPList();
    #endregion

    #region Denied
    /// <summary>
    /// Comma seperated string of denied IPs. Example "10.2.5.41,192.168.0.22"
    /// </summary>
    /// <value></value>
    public string DeniedSingleIPs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Comma seperated string of denied IPs with masks. Example "10.2.0.0;255.255.0.0,10.3.0.0;255.255.0.0"
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The masked I ps.</value>
    public string DeniedMaskedIPs { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the configuration key for denied single IPs
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The configuration key single I ps.</value>
    public string ConfigurationKeyDeniedSingleIPs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the configuration key for denied masked IPs
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The configuration key masked I ps.</value>
    public string ConfigurationKeyDeniedMaskedIPs { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// List of denied IPs
    /// </summary>
    IPList deniedIPListToCheck = new IPList();
    #endregion


    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether access to the core framework is authorized.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext">The HTTP context, which encapsulates all HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP request.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if access is authorized; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="httpContext"/> parameter is null.</exception>
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");

        string userIpAddress = httpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;

        try
        {
            // Check that the IP is allowed to access
            bool ipAllowed = CheckAllowedIPs(userIpAddress);

            // Check that the IP is not denied to access
            bool ipDenied = CheckDeniedIPs(userIpAddress);    

            // Only allowed if allowed and not denied
            bool finallyAllowed = ipAllowed && !ipDenied;

            return finallyAllowed;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Log the exception, probably something wrong with the configuration
        }

        return true; // if there was an exception, then we return true
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks the allowed IPs.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userIpAddress">The user ip address.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool CheckAllowedIPs(string userIpAddress)
    {
        // Populate the IPList with the Single IPs
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AllowedSingleIPs))
        {
            SplitAndAddSingleIPs(AllowedSingleIPs, allowedIPListToCheck);
        }

        // Populate the IPList with the Masked IPs
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AllowedMaskedIPs))
        {
            SplitAndAddMaskedIPs(AllowedMaskedIPs, allowedIPListToCheck);
        }

        // Check if there are more settings from the configuration (Web.config)
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationKeyAllowedSingleIPs))
        {
            string configurationAllowedAdminSingleIPs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ConfigurationKeyAllowedSingleIPs];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configurationAllowedAdminSingleIPs))
            {
                SplitAndAddSingleIPs(configurationAllowedAdminSingleIPs, allowedIPListToCheck);
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationKeyAllowedMaskedIPs))
        {
            string configurationAllowedAdminMaskedIPs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ConfigurationKeyAllowedMaskedIPs];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configurationAllowedAdminMaskedIPs))
            {
                SplitAndAddMaskedIPs(configurationAllowedAdminMaskedIPs, allowedIPListToCheck);
            }
        }

        return allowedIPListToCheck.CheckNumber(userIpAddress);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks the denied IPs.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userIpAddress">The user ip address.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool CheckDeniedIPs(string userIpAddress)
    {
        // Populate the IPList with the Single IPs
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DeniedSingleIPs))
        {
            SplitAndAddSingleIPs(DeniedSingleIPs, deniedIPListToCheck);
        }

        // Populate the IPList with the Masked IPs
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DeniedMaskedIPs))
        {
            SplitAndAddMaskedIPs(DeniedMaskedIPs, deniedIPListToCheck);
        }

        // Check if there are more settings from the configuration (Web.config)
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationKeyDeniedSingleIPs))
        {
            string configurationDeniedAdminSingleIPs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ConfigurationKeyDeniedSingleIPs];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configurationDeniedAdminSingleIPs))
            {
                SplitAndAddSingleIPs(configurationDeniedAdminSingleIPs, deniedIPListToCheck);
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationKeyDeniedMaskedIPs))
        {
            string configurationDeniedAdminMaskedIPs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ConfigurationKeyDeniedMaskedIPs];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configurationDeniedAdminMaskedIPs))
            {
                SplitAndAddMaskedIPs(configurationDeniedAdminMaskedIPs, deniedIPListToCheck);
            }
        }

        return deniedIPListToCheck.CheckNumber(userIpAddress);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Splits the incoming ip string of the format "IP,IP" example "10.2.0.0,10.3.0.0" and adds the result to the IPList
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ips">The ips.</param>
    /// <param name="list">The list.</param>
    private void SplitAndAddSingleIPs(string ips,IPList list)
    {
        var splitSingleIPs = ips.Split(',');
        foreach (string ip in splitSingleIPs)
            list.Add(ip);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Splits the incoming ip string of the format "IP;MASK,IP;MASK" example "10.2.0.0;255.255.0.0,10.3.0.0;255.255.0.0" and adds the result to the IPList
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ips">The ips.</param>
    /// <param name="list">The list.</param>
    private void SplitAndAddMaskedIPs(string ips, IPList list)
    {
        var splitMaskedIPs = ips.Split(',');
        foreach (string maskedIp in splitMaskedIPs)
        {
            var ipAndMask = maskedIp.Split(';');
            list.Add(ipAndMask[0], ipAndMask[1]); // IP;MASK
        }
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
}
```

Example usage:

1. Directly specifying the IPs in the code

   ```
    [FilterIP(
       AllowedSingleIPs="10.2.5.55,192.168.2.2",
       AllowedMaskedIPs="10.2.0.0;255.255.0.0,192.168.2.0;255.255.255.0"
   ```

   )]

   ```
   public class HomeController 
   {
   // Some code here
   }
   ```
2. Or, Loading the configuration from the Web.config

   ```
    [FilterIP(
       ConfigurationKeyAllowedSingleIPs="AllowedAdminSingleIPs",
       ConfigurationKeyAllowedMaskedIPs="AllowedAdminMaskedIPs",
       ConfigurationKeyDeniedSingleIPs="DeniedAdminSingleIPs",
       ConfigurationKeyDeniedMaskedIPs="DeniedAdminMaskedIPs"
   ```

   )]

   ```
   <configuration>
   <appSettings>
   <add key="AllowedAdminSingleIPs" value="localhost,127.0.0.1"/> <!-- Example "10.2.80.21,192.168.2.2" -->
   <add key="AllowedAdminMaskedIPs" value="10.2.0.0;255.255.0.0"/> <!-- Example "10.2.0.0;255.255.0.0,192.168.2.0;255.255.255.0" -->
   <add key="DeniedAdminSingleIPs" value=""/>    <!-- Example "10.2.80.21,192.168.2.2" -->
   <add key="DeniedAdminMaskedIPs" value=""/>    <!-- Example "10.2.0.0;255.255.0.0,192.168.2.0;255.255.255.0" -->
   </appSettings>
   </configuration>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the DB to store IP list then have some boolean property on the FilterIPAttribute class to specify which list you want to bring from Db so that you can have a control over it

```
[FilterIP(AllowedAdminSingleIPs =true,DeniedAdminSingleIPs=false)]
```

and then in AuthorizeCore method check these variables and make a Db call accordingly. You might want to use cache for better performance